# Why does Rider 2019.3.1 return an error when trying to install a NuGet package from a private repository?

Tags: .net-core, nuget, rider

I'm running Rider 2019.3.1 on macOS 10.15.2, and when I try to install a NuGet package, I get an error like the following (I have removed the address of our private repository):

```
Failed to retrieve information about 'AWSSDK.StepFunctions' from remote source 'https://<private repo>/api/nuget/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='AWSSDK.StepFunctions'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Failed to retrieve information about 'AWSSDK.StepFunctions' from remote source 'https://<private repo>/api/nuget/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='AWSSDK.StepFunctions'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
  at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode () [0x00040] in <92622ed7863541938d6ad8728c1e890c>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1[T].<GetAsync>b__0 (System.Threading.CancellationToken lockedToken) [0x003e8] in <3337e34b437e4961a8f2de48cf2685ed>:0 
  at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T] (System.String filePath, System.Func`2[T,TResult] action, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00212] in <2613e7f2f62d4d78a9ca66443392e7f5>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetAsync[T] (NuGet.Protocol.HttpSourceCachedRequest request, System.Func`2[T,TResult] processAsync, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000e7] in <3337e34b437e4961a8f2de48cf2685ed>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.RemoteV2FindPackageByIdResource.FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore (System.String id, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002ac] in <3337e34b437e4961a8f2de48cf2685ed>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at NuGet.Protocol.RemoteV2FindPackageByIdResource.FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore (System.String id, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00379] in <3337e34b437e4961a8f2de48cf2685ed>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.RemoteV2FindPackageByIdResource.GetPackageInfoAsync (System.String id, NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion version, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00096] in <3337e34b437e4961a8f2de48cf2685ed>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.RemoteV2FindPackageByIdResource.DoesPackageExistAsync (System.String id, NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion version, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ea] in <3337e34b437e4961a8f2de48cf2685ed>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.FindLibraryCoreAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00166] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider+<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<FindLibraryAsync>b__0 () [0x0007f] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.FindLibraryAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework targetFramework, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00170] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility+<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<FindLibraryFromSourcesAsync>b__0 () [0x00075] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryFromSourcesAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] providers, System.Func`2[T,TResult] action) [0x00160] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryByVersionAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] providers, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00298] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindPackageLibraryMatchAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] remoteProviders, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] localProviders, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002d9] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryMatchAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.String runtimeIdentifier, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] remoteProviders, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] localProviders, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] projectProviders, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] lockFileLibraries, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00354] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryEntryAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.String runtimeIdentifier, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteWalkContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000e0] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker.CreateGraphNode (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.String runtimeName, NuGet.RuntimeModel.RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate, NuGet.DependencyResolver.GraphEdge`1[TItem] outerEdge) [0x0020d] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker.CreateGraphNode (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.String runtimeName, NuGet.RuntimeModel.RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate, NuGet.DependencyResolver.GraphEdge`1[TItem] outerEdge) [0x00538] in <77c53f42bb4c4dc991a34360aa339d88>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.ProjectRestoreCommand.WalkDependenciesAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange projectRange, NuGet.Frameworks.NuGetFramework framework, System.String runtimeIdentifier, NuGet.RuntimeModel.RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker walker, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteWalkContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000be] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.ProjectRestoreCommand.TryRestoreAsync (NuGet.LibraryModel.LibraryRange projectRange, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] frameworkRuntimePairs, NuGet.Repositories.NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T] fallbackPackageFolders, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker remoteWalker, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteWalkContext context, System.Boolean forceRuntimeGraphCreation, System.Threading.CancellationToken token, NuGet.Common.TelemetryActivity telemetryActivity) [0x00188] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteRestoreAsync (NuGet.Repositories.NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T] fallbackPackageFolders, NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteWalkContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken token, NuGet.Common.TelemetryActivity telemetryActivity) [0x002f1] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x005c8] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.ExecuteAsync (NuGet.Commands.RestoreSummaryRequest summaryRequest, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000c3] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.CompleteTaskAsync (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] restoreTasks) [0x000ce] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.RunWithoutCommit (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] restoreRequests, NuGet.Commands.RestoreArgs restoreContext) [0x001db] in <ab830f5711cc4cd9b03b9e2396816a6c>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.DependencyGraphRestoreUtility.PreviewRestoreAsync (NuGet.PackageManagement.ISolutionManager solutionManager, NuGet.ProjectManagement.Projects.BuildIntegratedNuGetProject project, NuGet.ProjectModel.PackageSpec packageSpec, NuGet.ProjectManagement.DependencyGraphCacheContext context, NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommandProvidersCache providerCache, System.Action`1[T] cacheContextModifier, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] sources, System.Guid parentId, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001bd] in <f8f7798361a74e00b7ab7c2972093bf2>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.PreviewBuildIntegratedProjectActionsAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.Projects.BuildIntegratedNuGetProject buildIntegratedProject, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] nuGetProjectActions, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x004a7] in <f8f7798361a74e00b7ab7c2972093bf2>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.PreviewInstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x001d7] in <f8f7798361a74e00b7ab7c2972093bf2>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageDownloadContext downloadContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0009b] in <f8f7798361a74e00b7ab7c2972093bf2>:0 
  at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.InstallPackageAsync (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageIdentity packageIdentity, NuGet.PackageManagement.ResolutionContext resolutionContext, NuGet.ProjectManagement.INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] primarySources, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] secondarySources, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000d3] in <f8f7798361a74e00b7ab7c2972093bf2>:0 
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetInstallOperation+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<InstallAsync>b__0 (NuGet.ProjectManagement.NuGetProject nuGetProject, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000a5] in <69ff65df27804523b892fa15354acdab>:0 
  at JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetInstallOperation.InstallInternal (JetBrains.ProjectModel.IProject project, System.String packageId, System.String packgeUserStr, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Configs.NuGetFeedContext feedContext, System.Int32 nestedLevel, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Logging.NuGetNotificationMode mode, JetBrains.ProjectModel.NuGet.Operations.NuGetOperationReporter reporter, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] nativeInstall) [0x003e6] in <69ff65df27804523b892fa15354acdab>:0 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
  at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode () [0x00040] in <92622ed7863541938d6ad8728c1e890c>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1[T].<GetAsync>b__0 (System.Threading.CancellationToken lockedToken) [0x003e8] in <3337e34b437e4961a8f2de48cf2685ed>:0 
  at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T] (System.String filePath, System.Func`2[T,TResult] action, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00212] in <2613e7f2f62d4d78a9ca66443392e7f5>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetAsync[T] (NuGet.Protocol.HttpSourceCachedRequest request, System.Func`2[T,TResult] processAsync, NuGet.Common.ILogger log, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x000e7] in <3337e34b437e4961a8f2de48cf2685ed>:0 
  at NuGet.Protocol.RemoteV2FindPackageByIdResource.FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore (System.String id, NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceCacheContext cacheContext, NuGet.Common.ILogger logger, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002ac] in <3337e34b437e4961a8f2de48cf2685ed>:0
```

Running `dotnet add package AWSSDK.StepFunctions -v 3.3.103.18` in the terminal successfully installs the package, and Rider sees the package as being installed when I switch back to it.

I was having a problem with this on 2019.3, and the patch fixed it in a previous project, but when I started a new one, the error came back.  What gives?

EDIT:  Here are the contents of `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config`:

```
<!-- Generated by ICA CLI -->
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="artifactory" value="https://<private repo bits>/api/nuget/nuget" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <artifactory>
      <add key="Username" value="<username>" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="<password>" />
    </artifactory>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="0" />
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
</configuration>
```

And here are the contents of `~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated by ICA CLI -->
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="artifactory" value="https://<private repo bits>/api/nuget/nuget" />
  </packageSources>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="0" />
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the name and the version of the operating system that you use?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I edited my question to include my OS.

Comment: 1. Could you please also share the content of ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config and ~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config
2. Once you install the package via the terminal, do you have any errors during NuGet restore in Rider?

Comment: I've edited my question with the contents of those files.  After adding the package from the terminal, Rider seems to be fine.

Comment: @AndreyAkinshin: Is there any other data you need to diagnose this?